# Symfony 1.4 Doctrine reset data before tests

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

im trying to test symfony application behaviour by [BDD symfony plugin](http://everzet.com/sfBehatPlugin/) and im stucked because i realized i dont know how to reset database directly by PHP in my BDD bootstraping file :-/ .

Does anybody know how to reset it without loading fixtures? (Result has to be empty database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean reset on every test (eg running `test:all`), I have this in a `test/bootstrap/db.php` file and include it at the end of `unit.php` or `functional.php`

```
new sfDatabaseManager($configuration);

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineDropDbTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--no-confirmation","--env=test"));

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineBuildDbTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--env=test"));

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineInsertSqlTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--env=test"));
```

This assumes that `$configuration` is defined in eg your `unit.php` or `functional.php` file as it normally is by default.

The above is used with the built-in lime test suite, but I'm sure you can extend/implement it appropriately in your BDD bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but can't you just run build?

```
symfony doctrine:build --all
```

Comment: Yep but programmaticaly in tests bootstrapping, so richsage has a clue. Thank you too.